# JSTree events not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, jstree-search, jstree-dnd

I am using jsTree 1.0-rc1 with JQuery 1.12.4.

I am trying to fire events such as: `create.jstree`, `open_node.jstree`, and `__loaded.jstree` but non of it is firing.

I used both `'bind'` and `'on'` to hook the events to the Jstree but non of it worked.

I did this on `document.ready`, using code such as:

```
$("#MainTree").bind("create.jstree", function (event, data) {
    alert("hello");
});


$('#MainTree').on('__loaded.jstree', function (ev, data) {
    debugger;
    var firstNode = $('#MainTree ul li').first();
    $(firstNode).find('.jstree-checkbox').first().remove();
});
```

Please can you tell if there is anything wrong?

Comment: first check order of scripts and use $(document).on/bind(event, selector, callback) syntax which will fetch the element from document object.

Comment: @ABUdhay can you show an example please?

Comment: $('#MainTree').on('__loaded.jstree' ...  instead of this use like $(document).on('__loaded.jstree', '#MainTree', function(){}) and keep it at end of the body.

Comment: @ABUdhay I tried it but it still doesn't fire, but thanks anyway.